# Multiple Versions of SQL Reporting Services ReportViewer

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a simple ASP.NET application that use the SSRS ReportViewer control.

I was wondering if it is possible to support multiple versions of this control within the application?

My application is used by users who use a mixed bag of reporting services and the SQL Reporting Services ReportViewer 2010 (version 10.0) is not compatible with SSRS 2005, but the SQL Reporting Services ReportViewer version 9.0 is.

I would like them to be able to choose which version of reporting services they have and then the application choose the correct control.

Will having multiple versions of this referenced within the application cause conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple references will probably cause an issue in a single project.

As a workaround, try this:

Create 2 user controls in 2 different assemblies, 1 for each version.
In these projects add the correct version of the references needed for the report viewer.
Then specify in the reference settings that it is Spesific Version.

Then, import your two assemblies into your container project.

Now, simply load the correct user control based on the report that needs to be rendered.

Hope this helps.